# Как контролировать потоки в servlet-контейнере?

Tags: java, glassfish, servlet

Насколько я знаю, сервлет-контейнер каждый запрос обрабатывает как отдельный thread. Как мне организовать thread-pool или что-то типа того при работе в сервлет-контейнере? Можно ли в сервлете сделать проверку на наличие свободного thread, если их число огрничено? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужен thread pool, то используйте [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) и [Executors](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html). Хотя, текст вашего вопроса вызывает у меня подозрение, что вы хотите сделать что-то странное и неправильное.. то ли вы вообще понятия не имеете о чём спрашиваете.. вот если бы вы точнее сформулировали, чего вы хотите сделать.

Comment: ok, возможно сервлеты и не нужны. Клиент будет передавать на сервер сообщения по get/post. Затем эти сообщения будут передаваться на модемы. Модемов несколько. Поэтому мне нужен пул.

Comment: Я же ответил уже про это в вашем вопросе про модемы. Не надо трогать никакие сервлетные потоки, надо сделать нормальный модуль для работы с модемами и из сервлета обращаться к нему напрямую. Про то как сделать пул потоков я тут ответил.

Comment: Может быть вы знаете какой-нить opensource продукт с похожей архитектурой? Очень хотелось бы посмотреть по существу...

Comment: Не знаю.. найти трудно, но это делается совсем просто. Ровно так, как я описал в том ответе за исключением мелочей, которые мне могут быть неизвестны.